# How do I create custom RHEL image for Ubuntu MAAS?

Tags: maas

I'd like to create custom image to deploy RHEL by Ubuntu MAAS, but it seems maas-image-builder is deprecated and it doesn't support to build RHEL image.

Does anyone have idea to build custom image for Ubuntu MAAS?